# Type used in a using statement must be implicity convertible to System.Idisposible

Tags: c#

Quiero crear un objeto de tipo HistoryDA para después mandar llamar un método de dicho objeto, pero me marca el siguiente error al intentar hacerlo:

```
Type used in a using statement must be implicity convertible to System.Idisposible
```

Código de la clase HistoryBI:

```
 public static BaseErrorResult InsertHistory(int idVehiculo, DateTime FechaC, DateTime FechaV, int QR, string FotografiaE, string status, string dueño)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var da = new HistoryDA())
            {
                 da.InsertHistoryDA(idVehiculo,FechaC,FechaV,QR,FotografiaE,status,dueño);
            }
            return new BaseErrorResult();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new BaseErrorResult(ex);
        }
    }
```

Código de la clase HistoryDA:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Ned4Models;
using Ned4Models.PruebasQR;

namespace Ned4DataAccess.PruebaQR
{
    class HistoryDa
    {
        public HistoryDa()
        {

        }

        public void InsertHistory(int idV, DateTime fechaC, DateTime fechaV, int QR, string FotoE, string status, string dueno)
        {

           Historico history = new Historico();

            idV = history.VehiculoId;
            fechaC = history.FechaCreacion;
            fechaV = history.FechaVigencia;
            QR = history.CodigoQR;
            FotoE = history.FotografiaEvidencia;
            status = history.Estatus;
            dueno = history.Dueño;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al utilizar la cláusula `using` se espera que el objeto implemente la interfaz `IDisposable` y que por lo tanto implemente un método `Dispose`.

```
using (var da = new HistoryDA())
{
   ...
}
```

Esto significa que al terminar de ejecutarse el código dentro de las llaves de `using` se llamará automáticamente al método dispose sobre el objeto dentro de los paréntesis, en tu caso, sobre `da`.

Como la clase HistoryDA no implementa `IDisposable` no se puede utilizar en una cláusula `using`.

Entonces tienes 2 opciones, quitar el `using`:

```
var da = new HistoryDA()
da.InsertHistoryDA(idVehiculo,FechaC,FechaV,QR,FotografiaE,status,dueño);
```

o implementar la interfaz:

```
class HistoryDA : System.IDisposable
{
    ...

    void Dispose()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: realice la primera opción que me diste y quite el using pero cuando realice el resto del código me dijo que no existe mi método y ya limpie y re compile el programa para ver si era eso y me dijo que seguía sin existir. el punto es que si lo tengo en la clase el método que quiero llamar.

Comment: Tendría que saber como quedo tu código al final, pero si no moviste la clase HistoryDA, el hecho de quitar el using en la otra clase no debería generar un error de este tipo.

Comment: ya supe a que se debía y es que estaba tomando una clase que  ya estaba creada en otro lado y que me la tomaba por default, así que re modifique el nombre de la mía para evitar confusiones. gracias y saludos.